# regex for part number look ups

Tags: regex

I have been trying to figure out regex for two days now and I can't seem to get it to work. I'm trying to setup regex that'll find all of the part numbers for a specific part family, i.e. if I know all of the part numbers for this family use the following format:

[image: part number schema]

How would you specify: "The first character should be a 'C', followed by one of the following 4-character combinations, then another C, then any 3-digit number between 000 and 999 (has to be 3 characters, even if all zeros), then J, K, or M, then one of these characters or numbers" etc, etc.

Comment: Sorry Tom, could you provide some code pls? And in which language are you programming O_o ?

Comment: @LuckyFr I'm looking for it to language agnostic, just the regex patterns. This may be implemented in excel short term, and long term in a confluence/jira macro.

Comment: @Tom It might help you to play around with one of the online regex explainers, for example [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DleTd9/1) - that link should show you `^C(0402|0603|0805)C[0-9]{3}(J|K|M)(9|8|4|3|5|1|2|A)R?A?C?`. (*You* can type all the package sizes ;) )

Comment: @AndrewMorton Wow, that tool is super useful for debugging. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern would be

`C(0402|0603|0805|1206|1210|1808|1812|1825|2220)C([0-9]{3})([JKM])([1234589A])RAC`

Comment: `(J|K|M)` can be written easier and more efficiently as `[JKM]`. Same with the following pattern.

Comment: Yeah you're right

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, which language you use, but in C#, you can try this expression:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"C[0-9]{4}C[0-9]{3}[JKM]{1}";
        string input = @"C4550C455J";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Singleline;
        
        Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, options);
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}", m.Value, m.Index);
    }
}
```